# Auto Play Not Working on Add to Homescreen

Tags: mobile, youtube, homescreen, autoplay

Recently Google updated Chrome to allow autoplay on mobile devices if added to homescreen, however I can not get this to work.
https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/autoplay

```html
<div class="plyr">
  <div class="embed-responsive"> 
    <iframe 
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{VIDEO_ID}}?autoplay=1&rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" 
      allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" 
      width="100%" 
      webkitAllowFullScreen 
      mozallowfullscreen 
      allowFullScreen>
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've added the autoplay tag, but it's not autoplaying in my added to homescreen application.